# What is Hevar Android and why is it written on my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

My S6 Edge phone's lock screen shows me the date, and below that two light bulb emojis surrounding "Hevar Android"

What is this? A Google search showed me that hevar is a Texas IT company, but nothing about Hevar Android.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That looks like an appointment reminder. Can you check your calendar whether there's some entry? Not that I mean *you've* added it, but some app might have.

Comment: Can't seem to find any entries for that...

Comment: OK, was worth a try. As it's on the lock screen, another place to look for are the corresponding settings. Also worth checking: Any apps you've installed that have access to the lockscreen.

Comment: Found it! It was the owner information. Must be the name of the store owner or something.

Comment: Cool! May I suggest you [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then, and mark the answer "accepted"? Makes it easier for other people coming with a similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the settings app and click lock screen and security, then info and app shortcuts, and it's the owner information section.